# Polygamma sum problem ...

Tags: number-theory, analysis, special-functions, summation-method, polygamma

Hello guys i have a problem evaluating the following sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\frac{4x(3\pi ^{2}(n+1)^{2}+x^{2})}{(x^{2}-\pi ^{2}(n+1)^{2})^{3}}$$ It is obviously of the polygamma form but i cant find an idea to solve it. Writing it into partial fractions makes it diverge so i dont know where to go. Please give a hint or a solution, anything is helful. If we were to write it into part frac we would get $$\frac{(n^2+n)}{(x-\pi (n+1))^{3}}$$ which is similar to $\frac{1}{n}$ which diverges, therefore i need an idea that doesnt rely on it.